# Error handling on form load using OnError Resume Next

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to catch error on form load so I can call a function. `On Error Resume Next` is not catching error. I am trying to catch an error using `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DonorName FROM tblDonations")`. Is there a way around this? I am thinking that the `Err.Number <> 0` is returning `0` hence the next line is skipped. This code works well in access 2019 and 365 but not in access 2016. Please see below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
On Error Resume Next
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DName FROM tblDonations")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description & " Please relink to Backend file!", , "Backend missing"
    Call RelinkTables
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainform"
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. If it doesn't (no Msgbox) then I assume that tblDonations exists.

Comment: @Andre The MsgBox does not appear. The back-end file is moved therefore I was expecting the Msgbox to appear. If code is fine, could it be a possibility that the form is corrupted? Or possibly a more elegant way of dealing with this?

Comment: The Error number is  `0`

Comment: Try `msgbox rs.RecordCount `. `call` command is used for call assembler functions in QuickBasic for MSDos using a different calling convention. It it does nothing in Windows. When you test for errors you have to clear them. So you would call `err.clear` before calling `relinktables`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to work around this behaviour.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim rs As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DName FROM tblDonations")
On Error GoTo 0

If rs Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "rs Is Nothing", , "Backend missing"
    Call RelinkTables
End If

'...

End Sub
```

Comment: this seems to work well. Thanks for your insight.